# What would happen in Formula 1 if a stateless person wins a Grand Prix?

Tags: formula-1

There are about 12 million stateless people on Earth. What would happen if one of them wins a Formula 1 Grand Prix? What anthem gets played?

Comment: Good question. Don't know the answer without research, but in 1991 Belgian Bertrand Gachot raced under the Euro flag. Although he didn't get any podium finishes I think it's the most recent comparable example.

Comment: I'm closing this as opinion-based as there isn't a answer to this question right now, because there doesn't need to be one. It's not like a stateless person is just going to turn up and win the next Grand Prix; the FIA would sort something out if this ever became a possibility.

Comment: Seems like a premature closure to me since no-one has done the research *shrug* but I'm not a mod...

Comment: @PhilipKendall EDIT: I read further to enhance my answer before posting and came full-loop. I'm back in the realms of opinion now however there are pertinent facts worth posting. Original comment follows: "Further to this, I propose the question is reopened since an answer is eminently possible without resorting to opinion. (sat in my clipboard right now)"

Comment: I'm tempted to say that the anthem that gets played is that of your racing license, not your passport. Grosjean is a Swiss citizen, but has a French racing license and hence races under the French flag; pretty sure he'd have the French national anthem played, not the Swiss one.

Comment: @PhilipKendall As of 2021, this is now a possibility. Nikita Mazepin will be racing in F1 under a neutral flag, due to WADA sanctions against Russia, and as part of these sanctions, [the Russian anthem will not be played at the Russian GP or in the (admittedly unlikely) event that Mazepin wins a race](https://www.autosport.com/f1/news/154920/mazepin-set-to-race-under-neutral-flag-after-cas-ruling).